# Subversion - What tool will help me to package project?

Tags: svn

I have set up subversion on my computer

Is there a tool that can build a package for my project when i commit ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of project is it?
There are various continuous integration servers that can poll subversion for changes, and perform a build and run tests each time a new commit is found.
One such server that is quite popular is [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
Jenkins is primarely for building Java based projects, but I think there are plugins for building different kind of projects as well.

No matter what kind of technology your project is, I'm sure there's a continuous integration server available that fits your needs.

Comment: thank , Jenkin can run on local computer with no connect internet ?

Comment: Yes, Jenkins can run on your local computer. I believe it runs fine without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You want some sort of [post-commit hook](http://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101): a script that executes every time you commit.

There may also be some sort of continuous integration software for your particular project type, as @rlovtang mentions.

Answer (score 0):

It's is a javascript project and just package all file after time i commit

and i run it in my local computer, no connect to another server